# papertrail versioning with separate database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multiple-databases, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to log the change events of a model in a separate database using papertrail.

I'm using 
Rails 4.1.2

Ruby 2.1

Papertrail 4.0.0

Below is the code i have added in concerns

```
module Foo
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

 class Version < Base
  include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
 end

 class Topic < Base
   has_paper_trail class_name: 'Foo::Version'
 end
end
Foo::Base.establish_connection(:trail_development)
```

I have included this Foo in topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
end
```

When im trying to create, edit or delete a topic, this isnt working.

Reference https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/pull/289

Comment: You say "this isnt [sic] working". What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: @JohnBachir you're putting a bounty on a question about a 9 year old version of RoR and Paper Trail. Can you confirm that these are the versions that you want an answer for?

Comment: @TonyArra thanks for asking- no, not those versions, rails 6.1 and the most recent papertrail.

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 6.0 or higher, this can be done by creating an abstract `Version` class that connects to a separate database like so:

```rb
class AbstractVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  self.abstract_class = true
  connects_to database: { writing: :my_database, reading: :my_database }
end

class MyVersion < AbstractVersion
  # Optional: specify a different table name.
  # self.table_name = :my_versions
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail versions: {
    class_name: "MyVersion"
  }
end
```

In Rails, a model must be defined as abstract to use a different database connection.

PaperTrail allows you to define a custom Version class through extending its `PaperTrail::Version` base class.

This could be further abstracted by creating a module that adds the `has_paper_trail` call.